# Primes splits in a quadratic field and inert in a cubic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $K$ be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there a positive density of primes $p$ such that $p$ splits in $K$, and $p$ is inert in $F$. I guess the answer is yes, and that the Chebotarev density theorem could apply, but how do we apply it?

Comment: There are two cases: a) $K$ and the Galois closure of $F$ are disjoint; b) $K$ is the quadratic subfield of the Galois closure of $K$. In case a), you have to work in the Galois closure, in case b) you can apply Chebotarev directly.

Comment: There are two cases in case a), F is a cyclic cubic field or not. how could we apply Chebotarev?

Comment: If $F$ is cyclic, apply Chebotarev to the compositum $KF$.

Comment: Is there any reference to write it down formally?